# I am trying to connect to mysql using Grails 3. As soon as I create model and try to run application, I run into error and sqlexception

Tags: java, mysql, grails

`As soon as I create model and try to run application, I run into error and`sqlexception. Check below for my code, application.yml, build.gradle settings `and stack trace. Am I missing anything?

`I'm pretty new to Grails as well as stacktrace. Please pardon for mistakes.

`Build.gradle

```
runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36"
```

`Application.yml

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdb?useUnicode:yes&characterEncoding:UTF-8
            username: root
            password: YES

    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdb?useUnicode:yes&characterEncoding:UTF-8
            username: root
            password: YES
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdb?useUnicode:yes&characterEncoding:UTF-8
            username: root
            password: YES
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

`Model - Website.groovy

```
    package newapp

    class Website {
    long Web_ID;
    String Website;
    long Company_ID;

// getters and setters here    

    static constraints = {
        Web_ID(unique: true)
        Website(unique: true)
    }
    }
```

`Stack Trace

```
| Running application...
2017-03-14 15:01:19.036 ERROR --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1665)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

D:\BeanCracker\New Grails Workspace\NewApp>
```

Comment: should be clear from the log: your db user `root` has no rights to access your db or it doesn't exist

Comment: did you really have to put all those getters and setters here? our eyes are bleeding...

Comment: Apologies!!! DB exists in database as well as I've granted all access to the user root. Still the problem persists. Can you suggest what else could be wrong?

Comment: can you connect to your db with that user with some sql-tool?

Comment: I'm unable to connect to MySQL from windows command line. Using this command - mysql -u root                                                                 Access denied for user root@localhost

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql. Once you manage to somehow login to mysql follow the link create account and give permission

Comment: Thanks guys. I can now connect to MYSQL from windows command line. But, I'm NOT able to connect to MYSQL from grails application. Any suggestions/ideas?